# Windows Store Apps - ListView increase height when drag item

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have two ListViews where their size changing according to content. Now I need to drag item from one to another. Drag and drop works when there's atleast one item in destination list. But if there isn't any item in destination list, drop doesn't work because it's height is 0.

Is there any way I can overcome this issue.

Comment: put a dummy entry in the list and remove when there's at least one real one in it? enable the containing panel to respond to the drop? What's the UI look like - with the list empty and zero-height how would the user know what to do and that drag/drop is even available.  Whatever visual cue/element you are providing to indicate drag/drop enablement could be wired up to respond to the drop event essentially acting as a proxy for the (currently) empty list.

Comment: I want ListView's height to be 0 when there's no items in it. I'm using this in a UserControl where it acts like hierarchy. Is there any way drop can be detected from it's parent? Or make height increase when user drag item near to ListView? I checked about PointerEntered event of control which near to ListView, but it doesn't fires when we drag item.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the the `MinHeight` property of your `ListView`

Comment: No, I want ListView's height to be 0 when there's no items in it. :(